# The 'rel' attribute is not allowed in this context using PagedListPager

Tags: c#, pagedlist

We are using PagedListPager in MVC Umbraco to create a paginated results list. However it is automatically adding in tags such as:

```
<a rel="prev">&lt; Previous</a>
```

Yet our accessibility checker "Total Validator" is flagging it as an error:

> The HTML specification being tested against specifies that the
> attribute is not allowed due to special restrictions. See the HTML
> Living Standard.

We are using:

```
<nav aria-label="News pagination">
     @Html.PagedListPager(pagedResultList, page => (string.Format("?keyword={0}&type={1}&sort={2}&p={3}", keywordString, typeString, sortString, page)), new PagedListRenderOptions() { LiElementClasses = new List<string> { "pagination-container" }, DisplayLinkToNextPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always, LinkToNextPageFormat = "Next &gt;", DisplayLinkToPreviousPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always, LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "&lt; Previous", DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always, LinkToLastPageFormat = "Last &gt;|", DisplayLinkToFirstPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always, LinkToFirstPageFormat = "|&lt; First" })
</nav>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The analyzer is wrong, `prev` is a [valid link type](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/links.html#linkTypes).

If you can't tell the analyzer to ignore this error, you'll have to remove it from the PagedList library yourself, as it's hardcoded.

Depending on which PagedList library you use:

- TroyGoode's PagedList (deprecated, not maintained): https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs#L54
- dncuug's X.PagedList: https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList/blob/master/src/X.PagedList.Mvc.Core/HtmlHelper.cs#L83

Or process the resulting HtmlString yourself, which is nasty:

```
@{
    var pagedListHtml = Html.PagedListPager(...).ToString();
    pagedListHtml = pagedListHtml.Replace("rel=\"prev\"", "");
}
@Html.Raw(pagedListHtml)
```